# Purpose of tolerance when using violatededits in R

Tags: r, package

sorry if this has already been answered. I searched around a bit but couldn't find anything related.

I'm using the `editrules` package in R - and was validating some rules using `violatedEdits`. I noticed when checking the help page that there is a tolerance argument. Can somebody please explain to me what this tolerance argument is used for?

There was an example in my lecture notes that changed the tolerance to 0.000001 when checking whether the sum of two values were equal to a third value. It looks like there were some NA values in there, and some falsely reported violations. Once the tolerance was set to the above mentioned value, `violatedEdits` reports that the rule is not violated. (and also reports how many evaluated to NA because of missing values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a good idea of how this works from `?violatedEdits`. `violatedEdits` performs the following:

> ```
> For rules of the form Ax == b |Ax - b| <= tol is returned.
>
> For rules of the form Ax < b, Ax - b < tol is returned.
>
> For rules of the form Ax <= b Ax- b <= tol is returned.
> ```

where `tol` is the tolerance parameter you're referring to.

In other words, `tol` is tolerance in the sense that it allows rules to be violated by an amount specified for `tol` (equal to 0 by default in some cases and the square root of machina accuracy in others). By making the `tol` greater than 0 the examples in your lecture notes show that in a case when a rule was violated by some tiny amount it was considered not violated because `tol` was > the amount by which it was violated.